# Error : Xcode Library not found for -ljpeg

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

Just after installing `POD`, I'm encountering this issue below.

> ld: library not found for -ljpeg

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got the solution:
    1. Open Terminal
    2. Enter below code

```
brew uninstall jpeg && brew install jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform `pod install` or `pod update` you **must use** the **new** `<YourProject>.xcworkspace` file instead of the old `<YourProject>.xcodeproj` file.

It happens because `.xcworkspace` contains your `.xcodeproj` and the `pods`. If you just run `.xcodeproj` the `pods` will be missing.

With `.xcworkspace` you should be able to run normally.

Comment: Please stop posting the same answer multiple times. If a question is a duplicate of an existing one, please flag it as such. Thank you.